# Find out which local branches are out of sync with remote

Tags: git

Suppose I have a git repository with several branches. I suspect some of the branches were not pushed upstream, or are outdated, or both (i.e. diverged).

Is there a way to find out which branches are out of sync with remote with one command? (Writing a script is OK but I'd like to know if there's already such a script).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done a script. Turns out `git branch -v` gives the necessary info.

~/bin/git-total.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

for DIR in "$@"; do
    # Only git dirs interesting
    [ -d "$DIR/.git" ] && cd "$DIR" || continue

    # git branch -v gives ahead/behind info
    # using perl - sorry for this
    MOD=`git branch -v | perl -wlne '/^..(\S+)\s+([a-f0-9]+)\s+(\[ahead\s+(\d+)\])/ or next; print "# Branch ahead: $1"; '`;

    # a series of UGLY HACKs to get pretty-printing
    [ ! -z "$MOD" ] && MOD="
$MOD"
    git status | grep -q '^# Changes' && MOD="$MOD
# Uncommitted changes present"

    # print summary
    [ ! -z "$MOD" ] && echo -e "$DIR:$MOD"
    cd -
done
```

Answer (score 7):

This might help you: `git remote show origin` I am not sure but it works for me

Comment: It doesn't show what I need, but it turns out that `git branch -v` does.

Answer (score 1):

[The project `uncommitted`](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/uncommitted) does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to know if the remote has changed or not, you need at least one git fetch to update your remote references. After that git status will tell you if you are behind or ahead of the remote and how many commits.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do, just in a less interactive way. Git status only shows one branch, so I'll have to iterate through them, and probably stash my local changes (if any) before doing so.

Comment: Turns out `git branch -v` gives the necessary info.