# How to find a local branch that is not advanced to a remote branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How to find a local branch that is not advanced to a remote branch?
How to find all commits that is not push to remote respository on all local branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out which local branches are out of sync with remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210402/find-out-which-local-branches-are-out-of-sync-with-remote)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `for-each-ref`'s handy [formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-upstream) to output that info :

```
git fetch
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)" refs/heads | grep ahead
```

It will output only branches which are ahead of their remote counterpart.

---

Then if you want the unpushed commits list for a branch, do the following :

```
git log --oneline <yourBranch>@{upstream}..<yourBranch>

# or alternatively by switching branches
git checkout <yourBranch>
git log --oneline @{upstream}..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't to see it all in git remote storage, like github etc. ,because you haven't pushed that changes from your local.

On your local machine, in cmd line, or in IDE cmd line:

git log  - to see your commits
git branch - to see your branches

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
gitk --branches --not --remotes
```

If you do not have `gitk`, you can use

```
git log --oneline --branches --not --remotes
```

and look out for the branch annotations (which are printed in some color).